# I am not able to disable google auth captcha from iOS flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, authentication, captcha

How to disable captcha while I log in with iOS google firebase authentication?

I did upload APNS .p12 certificate for development and production too on firebase. I did enable the background to fetch, Remote Notification, Background Processing in ios Xcode.

But still, it's not disabled when I logged in from the iOS flutter Application.

Please advise me what step I have missed from my side for disabling captcha.

Answer (score 0):

[This Medium article](https://medium.com/@deepaklohmod6789/adding-firebase-phone-authentication-in-flutter-and-removing-recaptcha-for-authentication-38198e9a2867) explains it very well. I believe you just need to go into your project settings in Firebase and go to Safety Net and agree to the terms and conditions that pop up.

Comment: Vandad Nahavandipoor

Appreciate your answer but I need a solution for iOS. I am running an application in android device but it's working fine without asking captcha but the problem I am getting from iOS.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Generate Sha-1 and sha256 debug key by entering this

```
gradlew signingReport
```

[image]

[image]

1. click on Add fingerprint. add debug sha1 sha256 key here
2. Download new google-service.json to the android app folder
3. Add this code in while `FirebaseAuth`  instantiating

---

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
auth.setSettings(appVerificationDisabledForTesting: true);
```